# How to do code completion in Android studio for Dart?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, ide, code-completion

I found that the code completion will not works well for function(block)

for example , If I wrote a function, and the IDE will prompt for code completion

[image]
And if i press tab for code completion , the completion result code will be like this:
[image]

But the result I want is the content satified with the function type like this:
[image]

Is there any way to make the code completion more intelligent?

Comment: try pressing (ctrl + space) will show options

Comment: thanks @Aks, the ctrl + space can invoke the code completion with "          LayoutBuilder(builder:LayoutWidgetBuilder )"
 ,but the code I want generate is like "LayoutBUilder(builder:(context, constraints){}" ,Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: From your second image ->  you typed LayoutBuilder then remove the builder after (:) and then press ctrl+space

Comment: @Aks , in my macOS + Android studio , ctrl+space or select basic from code completion can't work as you said.

Comment: It's working in my macOs + Android studio, LayoutBuilder(builder: //press ctrl+space ). Try this once-> go to file -> Invalidate caches -> Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: @Aks ,the code generated by this in my project will be like this :LayoutBuilder(builder:(p0, p1) {
            
          }, Do you got the same p0&p1 code?

Comment: yes the code generated is like p0, p1. Actually the p0, p1 are the object names But when you take your cursor on p0, It'll show you the class for example it'll show you the class name like LayoutBuilder which is referred as p0 there.